# Multiple Counts in a single query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a simple way to achieve this query result to improve its performance. I prefer not to join two tables for every select.

```
select Product, LCTL, LQ, LCTQL from
(
(select 'Phone / HSI' as Product, (select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and c.category_long_name='m ECOMM ORD') as LCTL,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM ORD' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM HELD')) as LQ,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM ORD' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM HELD' or c.category_long_name='m ECOMM ORD')) as LCTQL from dual
union all

select '(Phone / HSI) + Prism' as Product,(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and c.category_long_name='m ECOMM PRISM') as LCTL,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM PRISM') as LQ,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='m ECOMM PRISM' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM PRISM')) as LCTQL from dual

union all
select '(Phone / HSI) + DTV' as Product,(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV') as LCTL,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM DTV') as LQ,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM DTV')) as LCTQL from dual

union all
select 'Total' as Product,(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='m ECOMM PRISM' or c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV')) as LCTL,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM PRISM' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM ORD' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM HELD')) as LQ,
(select count(1) as "LCTL" from tasks t,task_categories c where t.category_id=c.category_id and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))>=?1 and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'))<=?2 and (c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='m ECOMM PRISM' or c.category_long_name='m ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM DTV' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM PRISM' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM ORD' or c.category_long_name='CRIS ECOMM HELD' )) as LCTQL from dual)
)
```

Output Should be as below:

```
Product                 LCTL    LQ      LCTQL
Phone / HSI         17209   39849   57058
(Phone / HSI) + Prism   4095    6   4101
(Phone / HSI) + DTV 6192    1   6193


Total   10287   39856   50143
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query could be written this way:

```
SELECT
  product,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.category_long_name  = 'm ECOMM ORD'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LCTL,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.category_long_name  = 'CRIS ECOMM ORD' 
             OR c.category_long_name  = 'CRIS ECOMM HELD'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LQ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.category_long_name IN('CRIS ECOMM ORD',
                                        'CRIS ECOMM HELD',
                                        'm ECOMM ORD')     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LCTQ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.category_long_name = 'm ECOMM PRISM'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lccc,
  ...
  ...
  COUNT(*) AS "Total"
FROM tasks t
INNER JOIN task_categories c ON t.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= ?1
  and to_date(to_char(t.user_create_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= ?2
GROUP BY product;
```

Using the `CASE` expression, with `GROUP BY product`, you can do this in one query. This is the basic idea.

Also, you might need to use the [`pivot`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) operator in Oracle, but it is not clear if it would be possible to be written using the `pivot` operator or not.